# What does the word 「すまさんぞ」mean?

Tags: words

Here is the full sentence. An old man talking himself with this one about a boy who should have been staying at home but he should not.

かえってきやがったら ただでは**すまさんぞ**。

I'm not sure if it is conjugated from 済ます in a specific spoken dialect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

済ませる= ”I will let the matter pass”
済まさない= ”I will not let the matter pass”

すまさんぞ (済まさんぞ)= ”I will NEVER let the matter pass”